How to derive the the following integral in continuous time?
Here is a standard exogenous system in continuous time, where $\pi_t$ is the pricing kernel
\begin{align*}
\frac{dx_t}{x_t} &= \mu_x  dt + \sigma_x dB_{xt}\\
\frac{dz_t}{z_t} &= \mu_z  dt + \sigma_z dB_{zt}\\
\frac{d\pi_t}{\pi_t} &= -r_f dt - \gamma_x dB_{xt}- \gamma_z dB_{zt}
\end{align*}
Assume $\lambda_{ft}=\lambda_f \lambda_t =\lambda_f \lambda_H $ at time $t$. I know the following solution.
\begin{align*}
PVGO_{ft} &=  \mathbb{E}_t \bigg[ \int_{t}^{\infty} \frac{\pi_s}{\pi_t} \:\lambda_{fs} \:x_s z_s^{\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}} \: ds\bigg] = x_t z_t^{\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}}  G \\
G  &=   \lambda_f  \bigg[ \rho^{-1} + \frac{\mu_L}{\mu_L+\mu_H} (\rho+\mu_H+\mu_L)^{-1} \bigg] \\
\rho &= r+ \gamma_x \sigma_x - \mu_x - \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha} 
\bigg(\mu_x-\gamma_z \sigma_z - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2_z\bigg) - \frac{1}{2}\bigg( \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}\bigg)^2\sigma^2_z
\end{align*}
where $\lambda_t$ follows a two-state continuous-time Markov process $\lambda_t \in \{\lambda_L, \lambda_H\}$ with instant transition probabilities $\mu_L$ and $\mu_H$ and $\mathbb{E}[\lambda_t]=1$.
How is the solution derived?
How to derive the following integrals? Again assume $\lambda_{ft}=\lambda_f \lambda_H $ at time $t$
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}_t \bigg[ \int_{t}^{T} \frac{\pi_s}{\pi_t} \:\lambda_{fs} \:x_s z_s^{\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}}\:  ds\bigg]  
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}_t \bigg[ \int_{t}^{T} \frac{\pi_s}{\pi_t} \:\lambda_{fs} \:x_s z_s^{\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}}\: e^{-\kappa(T-s)} \: ds\bigg]  
\end{align*}
I'd appreciate if you can provide a detailed derivation!

There seems to be considerable mathematical detail missing in this exposition. (For ex: how is PVGO related to the 3 equations above? What is $\alpha$? What is $\lambda$, which switches between high and low values, some kind of growth rate?

Explain your notation. Nothing is standard starting with your very first line.
